# Serial.available is working only for the first time

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I am working on RFID. I am sending data through serial monitor and the Serial.available is not identifying the data after the first time, its working perfectly fine only once after reopening the comport.

I have tried all the possible changes I could do in the code. I want that when I run this code, then after entering the data in serial monitor it should show "Scan the mifare card" and after scanning the card it should perform read or write action.

```
#include <SPI.h>//include the SPI bus library
#include <MFRC522.h>//include the RFID reader library

#define SS_PIN 10  //slave select pin
#define RST_PIN 9 //reset pin
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);        // instatiate a MFRC522 reader object.
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;//create a MIFARE_Key struct named 'key', which will hold the card information


void setup()
 {
        Serial.begin(9600);        // Initialize serial communications with the PC
        SPI.begin();               // Init SPI bus
        mfrc522.PCD_Init();     
        //while (! Serial); // Wait untilSerial is ready - Leonardo
        //Serial.println("Enter data");
 }

String incomingStr;
byte blockcontent[16];
int count=0;
String arr2[6];
int arr3[6];
int u2=0;
String arr[16];
int arr1[16];
int u=0;
int y;
char action;
//int newc=0;

void loop()
{
 // Serial.println("bahar"); 
  if (Serial.available()) 
    {
      doReceive();
      int newc=0;       
      while(newc==0)
       {
         if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
            {
               if(count==0)
                   {
                       Serial.println("Scan your mifare card %");
                       count++;
                   }
            }
        else
            {
               newc=1;
            }
       }

     if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
       {
         return;
       }
     if(action=='%')
       {
         doWrite();
       }
     else if(action=='$')
       {
         doRead();
       }
     else if(action=='^')
       {
         for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; ++i) 
           { // read id (in parts)
              Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
              Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
           }
         Serial.print("*");
       }
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();   
  Serial.flush(); 
   }
}



void doReceive()
{
   incomingStr = Serial.readString();
   int sto=incomingStr.indexOf(')');
   action=incomingStr.charAt(sto+1);
   y=sto+2;
   for(int j=0;j<sto;j++)
    {
      if(incomingStr.charAt(j)!= ' ')
       {
         //Serial.print(incomingStr.charAt(j));
         //arr[u]=arr[u].concat(incomingStr.charAt(j));
         arr2[u2]+=incomingStr.charAt(j); 
       }
     else
       {
         //Serial.println(arr[u]);
         u2++;
       }
    } 
  for(u2=0;u2<6;u2++)
    {
      arr3[u2]=arr2[u2].toInt();
      key.keyByte[u2]=arr3[u2];
      //Serial.println(key.keyByte[u2]);
    }
 }
void doWrite()
{
  int block=1;
  for(int i=0;i<incomingStr.length();i=i+16)
  {
    if(block == 3 || block ==7 || block ==11 || block ==15 || block ==19 || block ==23 || block ==27 || block ==31 || block ==35 || block ==39 || block ==43 || block ==47 || block ==51 || block ==55 || block ==59 || block ==63)
      {
        block=block+1;
      }
    for(int u=0;u<16;u++)
      {  
        blockcontent[u]=0;
        //Serial.println(arr1[u]);
      }
    String s1=incomingStr.substring(y+i,y+16+i);
    s1.getBytes((char *) blockcontent, 30);
    writeBlock(block, blockcontent);  
    block=block+1;  
  }
  Serial.println("Data written successfully*");
}
void doRead()
{
  int block=1;
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    { 
      if(block == 3 || block ==7 || block ==11 || block ==15 || block ==19 || block ==23 || block ==27 || block ==31 || block ==35 || block ==39 || block ==43 || block ==47 || block ==51 || block ==55 || block ==59 || block ==63)
        {
          block=block+1;
        } 
      byte readbackblock[18];
      readBlock(block, readbackblock);//read the block back  
      //Serial.print("Block contains: ");
      for (int j=0 ; j<16 ; j++)//print the block contents
        {
           Serial.write (readbackblock[j]);//Serial.write() transmits the ASCII numbers as human readable characters to serial monitor 
        }

     //Serial.println();
     block=block+1;
    }
  Serial.println("*");
 }
```

Comment: `I have tried all the possible changes I could do in the code.` First of all, you could make it reabable by proper indenting.

Comment: `arr2[u2]+=incomingStr.charAt(j);` I don't understand this. But I doubt, it's doing want you want

Comment: @user55609 please use proper indentation wile programming. It help other to understand your code easily.

Comment: add some test point in you code after every module execution, that will help you to get the error.

Comment: what string you sent from serial monitor?

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to add these debugging prints here to see if this while loop is becoming infinite:

```
  while(newc==0)
   {
     if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
        {
           if(count==0)
               {
                   Serial.println("Scan your mifare card %");
                   count++;
                   **Serial.println("test0")*
               }

        }
    else
        {
           newc=1;
           **Serial.println ("newc=1")**
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr2` have size `6`. Have you made sure that here

```
...    
for(int j=0;j<sto;j++)
{
  if(incomingStr.charAt(j)!= ' ')
   {
     arr2[u2]+=incomingStr.charAt(j); 
   }
 else
   {
     u2++;
   }
}
...
```

you are not writing beyond the bounds of that array?

Moreover, you never explicitly set the initial value of `u2` before starting this cycle - whatever was left in global variable `u2` from the previous uses will serve as the staring value for this cycle.

Judging by cursory examination of the rest of your code, only the very first call to `doReceive` will begin this cycle with `u2 == 0`. After that every time you call `doReceive`, you will start this cycle with `u2 == 6`, definitely overflowing the array and destroying the content of adjacent memory locations. The behavior is undefined.

I guess it is a "global variables strike again" kind of situation. Why on Earth is `u2` made a global variable???

It is quite possible that you can "fix" your code by simply adding `u2 = 0;` before the above cycle. But even after that the code will remain in a rather precarious state.